# Though and Despite

Tags: grammar

We want you to be aware that we're doing our utmost, ------- we will not be able to provide you with a personalized experience on our website.

(A) despite

(B) though

The answer given is "though". I don't know why "despite" was wrong. Please tell me about it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "Despite" takes NPs and non-finite clauses as complement, but it can't take finite clauses.  The complement in your example is a finite clause, so "despite" would be ungrammatical. By contrast, "though" does take NPs and finite clauses, so it's the correct choice in your example.

Answer (score 3):

When you connect two clauses, you normally use a conjunction, and "though" is a conjunction.

"despite" is a preposition, it needs to be followed by a noun or verb phrase phrase, not a whole clause. E.g.

Verb phrase:

> We want you to be aware that we're doing our utmost, despite   **not being able** to provide you with a personalized experience on our website.

or noun phrase:

> We want you to be aware that we're doing our utmost, despite **the fact that** we are not able to provide you with a personalized experience on our website.

Comment: The use of 'despite' in your examples implies that an 'inability to provide a personalized experience' presents an obstruction to 'doing our utmost' (which has been overcome). The obstruction is to the perfect **result** of the effort, not to 'doing our utmost', which continues unabated, so personally, I don't think 'despite' makes sense in this context at all.

Comment: I think it's better to say that although "despite" can take a non-finite clause (like the one you cited) as complement, it can't take a finite clause, as seen in the OP's example

Comment: @RobinBetts I think you're right. I was concentrating on the grammar, not as much on the sensibility. In fact, to make more sense the sentences should be reversed.

Comment: @Barmar .. it's a subtlety, no problem.. it's just what struck me when I read the phrases.